# Changing to 24-Hour Time on iPhone 6, iOS 9 leads to app crash

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I developed an application in which I use a singleton for keeping a single instance of an NSDateFormatter.

My date formatter is initialized as below:

```
timeDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
timeDateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier:EN_US_POSIX_LocaleIdentifier)
timeDateFormatter.dateFormat = StringDateType.DetailSigningHour.rawValue
let EN_US_POSIX_LocaleIdentifier = "en_US_POSIX"
```

With 24-Hour Time turned off the application runs as it should, but when going to Settings-->General-->Date&Time and turning on 24-Hour Time, then going and tapping on the app icon, the app tries to come up and then immediately exit.

I read that this may be an unknown issue for Apple.

Can you help me with some more information about this?

**Update**

When the system time was changed from 12-hour format to 24-hour format, my date formatter was messed up.

The good part is that the system is sending a notification (NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification) letting you know that the locale has changed. All what I have done was to add an observer for this notification and to re-initialize my date formatter.

Setting the locale to en_US_POSIX, you force the 12-hour mode, regardless of the user's 24/12-hour mode setting.

Comment: What is the .dateFormat value?

Comment: Provide details about the crash. What is the error? Where exactly does it crash?

Comment: maybe first you should check the crash-log of that _unknown-issue_... and try to fix your app, hm?

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to *assume* that you're force-unwrapping the result of `timeDateFormatter.dateFromString` with a wrong date format.

If you do something like this:

```
let timeDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
timeDateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier:"en_US_POSIX")
timeDateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
```

And force-unwrap the result:

```
let d = timeDateFormatter.dateFromString("11:42")!
```

You will get a crash at runtime if the date string is more than 12h:

```
let d = timeDateFormatter.dateFromString("13:42")!  // crash
```

because `"hh:mm"` deals with 12h format only.

To use 24h format you should use `"HH:mm"`:

```
timeDateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
```

And to avoid crashes, avoid force-unwrapping:

```
if let d = timeDateFormatter.dateFromString("11:42") {
    print(d)
} else {
    // oops
}
```

*If my diagnostic is wrong, please add details to your question. :)*

Answer (score 1):

I do not know that issue, however I always used my formatters this way, maybe this is also convenient to you.

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle // here are different values possible, and all are good declared.
formatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle // Same possible values like in timeStyle.
```